# OpenTSDB: adding tag in row key disturbs rowkey formation and causes issues like hotspotting

Tags: opentsdb

Currently, we are using the command

```
IMPORT(http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/cli/import.html)
```

to bulk insert data in OpenTSDB 2.2.0, we haven't written any JAVA code to insert data.

Earlier we were inserting data like:

```
metric_name timestamp value tag1=value1
```

but now we have added one more tag in our data and that has caused HBase hotspotting, now our data looks like:

```
metric_name timestamp value tag1=value1 tag2=value2
```

Do you think adding one more tag can cause hotspotting? If yes then How can we fix this?

In previous data we didn't applied SALTING and i believe if we apply SALTING to new data then we can't access previous data.